# Optimising SQL Query With Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have the following three tables:

Venues, Events, Instance.

Events have a Venue (Venues have many events), and Events have many Instances.

For example, the Event "Terminator2" is a film that has a certain cinema as its Venue and will have many instances of that film (date times).

I need to run a query, which gives me a lost of Venues that satisfies the following:

Venue location is x. 
Venue has Events of a certain type.
Thos Events have Instances within a certain time period.

I have achieved the first two with a JOIN on venue and Event (Events have a foreign key for the venue) and a WHERE clause to make sure the events are of a certain type. Now I need to make sure that the Events ALSO have Instances within a certain time period.

Do I add another JOIN on the Instances table (the Instances have a foreign key for an event) and another WHERE clause there?

What kind of performance should I expect from a double join, double where query like this?

Are there any suggestions as to doing this a better way?

Comment: Is premature optimization really the root of all evil? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211414/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: @Rubens: The idea that normalization is for performance demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of what normalization *is* - referencial integrity.

Comment: @Rubens yes, I gave good thought to the fact that for performance I could have multiple Events, each with a different time etc. And somehow link together the events so that if one changed I could change the others, but after thinking about the consequences there were too many issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT v.Venue, e.Event, i.Instance
FROM Venue v
INNER JOIN Event e
ON v.EventID = e.EventID
INNER JOIN Instance i
ON e.EventID = i.EventID
WHERE v.Venue = 'X'
AND e.Event = 'Terminator2'
AND i.InstanceDateTime BETWEEN '11/01/2009' AND '11/01/2009 23:59:00'
```

Or you can include your criteria in the joins which may perform better, in some cases.

```
SELECT v.Venue, e.Event, i.Instance
FROM Venue v
INNER JOIN Event e
ON v.EventID = e.EventID
AND e.Event = 'Terminator2'
INNER JOIN Instance i
ON e.EventID = i.EventID
AND i.InstanceDateTime BETWEEN '11/01/2009' AND '11/01/2009 23:59:00'
WHERE v.Venue = 'X'
```

Comment: That's interesting, I hadn't considered there was a difference in where the criteria was - I'll look into that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an EXISTS clause:

```
select * from venues v
where v.venue_type = 'X'
and exists (select null
            from   events e
            join   instances i on i.event_id = e.event_id
            where  e.venue_id = v.venue_id
            and    e.event_type = 'Y'
            and    i.instance_date between :date1 and :date2
           )
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with EXISTS... off to do some reading, thanks!